# Efficient way to avoid duplicate signal subscriptions

Tags: c++

I have an API which will subscribe for a signal. There are many signals and can increase in the future. How do I avoid duplicate subscriptions?  For example:

```
bool subscribe(signal);

subscribe(signal_one)
subscribe(signal_one)
```

It should not allow two subscriptions when two clients A and B try to subscribe to the same signal.

My approach is to maintain a container where I will store all of the subscribed signals and I will check that list before subscribing. But this looks like it is not a very efficient way.

Comment: Sounds fine to me. What do you think is not efficient about it exactly?  As for the container itself, a simple array or `std::(unordered_)map` will probably suffice, where the array/map is indexed by the signal IDs.  When subscribing to a signal, if its slot in the array/map is already occupied, don't allow the subscription.  Just make sure the accepted subscription gets unsubscribed eventually so the signal's slot can be cleared out.

Comment: Double/multi subscription of same receiver to a signal might be done intentionally and I wouldn't do anything to forbid/prevent this. What I consider more important: when a subscriber (object) is destroyed it must be unregistered from signal's subscriber list. (Otherwise, you get "dangling signal handlers" with similar effects like dangling pointers.) One option to solve this are so-called trackable subscribers (got this term from sigc++) which are disconnected automatically. Another option is to return connection handles which subscriber can store and use for disconnect on destruction.

Comment: Usually double subscribe and double unsubscribe are signs of errors.